# Cyrillic letters in Git Bash

Tags: git, cmd, cygwin

I'm trying to change the working directory to `C:/Users/Абырвалг` for initializing git repo there, but it doesn't work. I can't type cyrillic letters in Git Bash whereas I can do this in cmd.exe. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you positive it's about Cygwin? The term "Git bash" is typically used when discussing Git for Windows and the bash shell it includes.

Comment: I have the same issue! Could anybody help to solve it, please?
And I don't want to use Cygwin or something else..

Answer (score 4):

I found the following steps helpful:

1. Run `Git Bash`
2. Right-click and select `Options...`
3. Select `Text` group at the left
4. Change Font to `Consolas`
5. Select `C` as `Locale` and `UTF-8` as `Character set`
6. Apply and Save.

[image: Git Bash Options]

7. In the terminal execute:

```sh
git config --global core.quotepath false
```

8. In rare cases, execute in the terminal as well

```sh
export LANG='C.UTF-8'
```

Now you can create a file with Cyrillic symbols in the name and execute `git status`:

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Maxx/test/.git/
$ touch Абырвалг
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        Абырвалг

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the git shell in [mintty](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/). Download the msys version, put it in your `Program Files\Git\bin` directory and run it (create a shortcut) with `mintty -`.

This will make unicode input work, and you will also get other improvements (especially better resizing and copy&paste).

Comment: while mintty is nice for resizing, unfortunately it does not support unicode input.

Comment: It definitely does on my machine. While the default prompt does not.

Comment: For me it is completely opposite. In `cmd` prompt, I can enter cyrillic letters without any trouble, and `git init привет` works fine. However, if I start mingw `bash` or `mintty`, trying to enter cyrillic letters simply does not work - it prints something like `:\350\342\345\362` instead. This is Windows 7 x64 (standard English).

Comment: Mh, I’m on Windows XP. But note that in `cmd` unicode works for me too – just not in the git bash. If you have unicode problems in mintty, try changing its settings.

Comment: @mvp in my case there was `~/.bash_profile` that redefined `LC_ALL=C` and thus disabled all mintty settings. After removing that `~/.bash_profile` mintty worked!